# jax-rs ClientBuilder in MobileFirst adapter on IBM Liberty

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jax-rs, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters

My goal is to use the *jax-rs* client to connect to a back-end inside the *MobileFirst* Java adapter, but I'm really stuck and need help.

The code that throws the exception:

```
javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
```

The Exception that was thrown:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder`

The code is inside the Java adapter on *MobileFirst server version 8.0* deployed on *IBM Liberty server*.

*jaxrsClient-2.0* and *jaxrs-2.0* features are enabled in the server feature manager in `server.xml`.

```
<feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
<feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
```

The application class is loaded configured like this:

```
<application id="mfp" name="mfp" location="mfp-server.war" type="war">
  <classloader delegation="parentLast" apiTypeVisibility="spec, ibm-api, third-party"></classloader>
</application>
```

Here is the exception trace:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:103)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
        at 
...............................
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:83)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClientBuilder
        at com.ibm.mfp.server.core.shared.ParentLastClassLoader.findClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:192)
        at com.ibm.mfp.server.core.shared.ParentLastClassLoader.loadClass(ParentLastClassLoader.java:165)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:113)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:206)
        at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newBuilder(ClientBuilder.java:86)
        ... 69 more
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar requirement, I did try out a number of combinations before resolving the exception.
I am not sure why liberty is not providing with client implementation classes..
you could try including jersey-client through maven pom.xml..

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

In Server.xml remove the features

```
<feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
<feature>jaxrsClient-2.0</feature>
```

and just add below feature.

```
<feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

Liberty *IS* providing a client implementation, but the parentLast classloader delegation is preventing it from being used.

It would appear that MobileFirst is packaging Jersey, in which case, the Liberty's JAX-RS features should be disabled so that Jersey is used instead. This may require you to change how dependencies are declared in the maven/gradle artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in WebSphere Liberty that was fixed in 16.0.0.4.  If the classes that are creating a new instance of the JAX-RS client is packaged in an OSGi bundle (either in an OSGi application or as part of a Liberty feature), then the JAX-RS client runtime cannot find the META-INF/services file that specifies Liberty's JAX-RS client implementation class (based on CXF) -- and so the JAX-RS runtime will fall back to the Jersey implementation, which won't be found unless you package it with your app.

The fix for this issue is described [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI71887). Basically, Liberty makes the META-INF/services file available to OSGi bundles.

Answer (score 0):

The fix from Suresh worked. I just needed to add more dependencies in my pom.xml though. I don't think I need Moxy here.. will optimize further.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b61</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0-b42</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```